# How do I change this JButton to not take up the whole width?

Tags: java

I used the internet as a resource to help me make a JButton but for some reason I cannot get it to a normal size. I have changed the dimensions and messes around a lot but it is not working.

Here is my code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class ScreenSaver {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JButton button = new JButton();
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();

        button.setSize(100, 100);
        panel.add(button);


        frame = new JFrame ("Screen Saver");
        frame.setSize(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize()); 
        frame.setUndecorated(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setContentPane(panel);
        frame.setBackground(new Color(1.0f,1.0f,1.0f,0.1f));
        frame.setResizable(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);


    }
}
```

Comment: If you use `GridLayout` , your button will only fill one cell of the grid.

Comment: @Berger What other layout could I use?

Comment: Try without passing a layout manager in the constructor, the default layout manager (FlowLayout ) of the `JPanel` should be fine.

Comment: @Berger Can you post how to do that?

Comment: Just do `JPanel panel = new JPanel();`

Comment: @Berger Seems to have worked but it is not listening when I change the size now...

Comment: What size should it have ?

Comment: @Berger I put 100, 100 and the size did not change. I updated the code in the original post

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does JButton control it's size?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20336914/how-does-jbutton-control-its-size)

Comment: Check the above topic, you will see plenty of answers.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
frame.setLayout(null);
```

then you can

```
button.setLocation(x,y);
```

It will help you to place Java components in the locations you want. 
Otherwise default Java Layout is applied to your Frame and then you cannot fully customise design!

Remember then you need to customise all components you are adding to JFrame. (setSize, setLocation to JPanel as well.)